# In magento 2 How to import image from ftp server having restricted access

Tags: magento2, import, csv

The ftp can be accessed only through credentials can Iget images from that ftp for magento.
Is that Possible?

Comment: you need the access of FTP creds for the uploading the data

Comment: yeah i have access for that , I have credentials but I don't know where to give